# the basis of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i am given this matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&-1\\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and the basis should be these vectors: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \quad\text{and}\quad \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix} $$

how come this? i am stuck, please can you give me the clue? i was looking for eigenvectors, but suddenly it says, the solution is these basis vectors. then i am stuck, so is the basis eigenvector generally?

EDIT: original matrix is this:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2&1&1&-1\\ 0&1&-1&1 \\ 0&0&3&0 \\ 0&-2&-1&4 \end{pmatrix}$$
then i solved characteristic polynom: $det(A-\lambda E_4)$ and came to polynomial with roots 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you mean basis _of the kernel_ of this matrix? Basis of a matrix makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the basis of the kernel of the matrix (when regarded as representing a linear map), that is, of the eigenspace relative to the eigenvalue zero.

**Concerning the original matrix,**
you should be able to see that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
are eigenvectors with respect to the eigenvalue $2$, while
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}
$$
are eigenvectors with respect to the eigenvalue $3$.

Comment: @doniyor, please post the original matrix.

Comment: What is '*eigenvalue formula*' that you have set them into??

Comment: thanks but you didnot answer my question. my question is how these two vectors come as solution?

Comment: @doniyor, if $A$ is the *original* matrix, then the two vectors you name come out as the solutions $x$ to $A x = 2 x$.

Comment: please explain me the solution depending on the matrix that i gave first. $A'x=0$ $\rightarrow$ those two vectors. why and how???

Comment: @doniyor, if $A'$ is the first matrix you gave, then your two vectors are a basis for the space of the solutions of $A' x = 0$. In fact, if $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^{t}$, then $A' x = 0$ gives the linear system $x_2-x_4 = 0 = x_3$, whose solutions are $(a,b,0,b)^{t} = a (1,0,0,0)^{t} + b (0,1,0,1)^{t}$, for $a, b$ real, so you see those two vectors are a basis of the space of solutions.

Comment: $x_3=0$ is fix and known, but $x_1,x_2,x_4$ can be set so that the equation becomes $0$, right?

Comment: @doniyor, yes, $x_1$ can be arbitrary, while $x_2$ and $x_4$ must be equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Let the matrix be $A$ and the vectors be $x,y$. Have you calculated $Ax$ and $Ay$?

Then you found that $Ax=\lambda x$ and $Ay=\mu y$ for some $\lambda,\mu$ numbers. What are these? Is there more eigenvalue?

Comment: the eigenvalues are 2, 3. then i set eigenvalues to eigenvector formula and came to this matrix.